# Eclipse: javax.annotation PostConstruct is not called

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, fedora-29

I am using Fedora 29 and have attempted to try out a simple plugin example by creating a new Plugin Project and used the "View contribution using 4.X API" template.

I have provided the system property of:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.e4.core.di.debug=true
```

In my VM arguments under eclipse.

After enabling that debug I get the following message:

```
!MESSAGE Possbible annotation mismatch: method "public void hello.parts.SampleView.createPartControl(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite)" annotated with "javax.annotation-api:1.2.0:javax.annotation.PostConstruct" but was looking for "javax.annotation.PostConstruct [via bootstrap classloader]"
```

What does this error message mean and how can I resolve it?

Here is snippet of the example of the eclipse plugin containing the PostConstruct annotation.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Optional;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IServiceConstants;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

public class SampleView {
    private Label myLabelInView;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        System.out.println("Enter in SampleE4View postConstruct");

        myLabelInView = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        myLabelInView.setText("This is a sample E4 view");

    }
```

Edit:

Manifest.mf file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Hello
Bundle-SymbolicName: hello;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: javax.inject,
 org.eclipse.osgi,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Automatic-Module-Name: hello
Import-Package: javax.annotation
```

Edit 2:

After examining the jars for javax.annotation (it is called javax.annotation-api instead of javax.annotation...) I found that they have a symbolic link to a glassfish implementation:

```
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/javax.annotation-api_1.2.0.jar -> /usr/share/java/glassfish-annotation-api.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/javax.el-api_3.0.0.jar -> /usr/share/java/glassfish-el-api.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar -> /usr/share/java/atinject.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/javax.servlet-api_3.1.0.jar -> /usr/share/java/glassfish-servlet-api.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/javax.servlet.jsp_2.3.2.b01.jar -> /usr/share/java/glassfish-jsp-api/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar
```

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF for the plug-in

Comment: Do you also have a `javax.annotation_xxxx` plugin? Try adding `javax.annotation` to the `Require-Bundle` list to force the correct plugin.

Comment: okay, ill give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the wrong plug-in is being picked by `Import-Package`. There should also be a `javax.annotation` plugin which is the correct one. Try adding `javax.annotation` to the `Require-Bundle` list to force that to be used:

```
Require-Bundle: javax.inject,
 javax.annotation,
 org.eclipse.osgi,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations
```

Comment: Yes that does seem to work, is that good practise? Should the javax.annotation be a require-bundle as opposed to an import bundle? Using the import does work on windows and other linux distributions. Is it safer to always require bundles?

Comment: I'm not sure. There were some changes a few releases ago to just use Import-Package for javax.inject and javax.annotation but that is clearly wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In spring you need add this line in application context, i hope to help you

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```